# Fetching data in vue.js without changing the store state?

Tags: vue.js, store, vuex

I have a vue.js SPA with a vuex store. Inside my application I have a view for my user. This user comes from the database and is loaded via the vuex store. All fine.

Now my problem is, that I need to load another user into the same view - this second user is related to my first user. When I am loading this second user via the vuex store, the first user gets overwritten.

Is there a good practice to load another user without overwriting the vuex-store user?

My current solution - the first snippet is the vuex-stored first user:

```
[actions.LOAD_USER](context, id) {
        return UserRepository.load(id)
            .then((user) => {
                context.commit(mutations.SET_USER, user.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                throw new Error(error);
            });
    }
```

And the second snippet is how i load my second user:

```
[actions.GET_USER](context, id) {
        return UserRepository.load(id);
    }
```

This is working, but I am asking you if you have a better solution?

Comment: You haven't added your mutation that is updating your user. So I can't see what you're doing wrong. You could add the second user by its id to the users collection. Is something like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/a7kfdqz6/) working for you?

Comment: There is no need for updating the user, i just want to load another one. I have a view representing user 1 and a dropdown representing a list of all users.

Comment: the only reason to run an action/mutation in the store (vuex) is if you want to update the stored state. from what you're showing, there's no need to call the mutation. so i'd drection call `UserRepository` directly from the component itself as a method.